# Passing two parameters to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to send a javascript function 2 parameters like this:

```
var par1;
var par2;

$('#somediv').append('<div onclick="somefunction('+par1+','+par2+');"></div>');
```

i'm creating a lot of divs like this one and all dynamicaly, i just need to find the correct way to pass the par1 and par2 to the operate them later.

right now only par1 is ok, par2 is undefined (they both has string value).

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is in `par1`/`par2`, strings? Probably need to escape them...

Comment: I assume this is jQuery, correct the tags if I'm wrong.

Comment: It's not the best way of doing things, but you can use `eval`

Comment: What is the expected output? I see several problems, one of them being that if it works, you've got an empty div that the user can't click on.

Comment: @gdoron: How would `eval` help here?

Answer (score 2):

That's because par1 and par2 are undefined in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the `var1` and `var2` with some default value.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do fancy stuff like this is using `.live`, `.delegate`, or `.on` in jQuery.

```
var par1; // assuming these get values at some point
var par2; // assuming these get values at some point
$('#somediv').append('<div class='fancyDiv'></div>');
$('#somediv').on("click", ".fancyDiv", function() {
   someFunction(par1, par2);
}))

// use delegate instead of on if you're in jQuery 1.6 or lower
$('#somediv').delegate(".fancyDiv", "click", function() {
   someFunction(par1, par2);
}))
```

Comment: You can make it even more simple and just attach a click event to the element directly: `$('<div>').click( function() {...} ).appendTo('#somediv');`

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to know from the limited context if there are more than one of these divs and how it's being used. Good point though!

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `onclick` e.g.

```
var par1 = 'par1';
var par2 = 'par2';

$('<div>Click</div>').appendTo('#somediv').click(function(){
    somefunction(par1, par2)
})

function somefunction(v1, v2){
    alert(v1+" "+v2);
} 
​
```

See it in action http://jsfiddle.net/anuraguniyal/gjz72

But it depends from where you are getting par1 and par2, if they are related to div and you need to have different one for each div, you should add them in html as data attribute e.g.

```
$('<div data-par1="par1" data-par2="par2" >Click</div>').appendTo('#somediv').click(somefunction)

function somefunction(){
    alert($(this).attr('data-par1')+" "+$(this).attr('data-par2'));
} 
​
```

See it in action http://jsfiddle.net/anuraguniyal/gjz72/14/

Answer (score 0):

`perimeterBox` is function here

```
var perimeterBox = function(length,width)
{
    return length+length+width+width;
};

perimeterBox(5,5);
```

Comment: Because SO want to be an archive of answers and questions, please add some explanations.